# How to calculate proper timeout or ETA value

Tags: performance, service, time, timeout, statistics

The problem is as follows: I have a service broker which distributes different types of tasks to workers. These tasks are of different size and complexity and thus require a different amount of time to process.

Now I would like to calculate a time-out value for each type of service, so that after it has elapsed the client can be notified that the task took to long, and that likely something went wrong.

There are two options which I've tried, but both have flaws.

1. Do not calculate the time-out, but make it an configurable setting (annoying since it's pretty arbitrary)
2. Start with a very generous time-out and after each task calculate some sort of running statistic (like a running average + variance). This has the problem that it converges to the mean since longer running tasks get censored. Eventually allowing a far too narrow band of task durations.

Since the tail of the distribution of task durations is likely long (i.e. longer than a normal distribution) it is likely that some more complicated statistic is needed.

Is there an accepted way of calculating time-out values based on task durations?